# How to make an IDE treat a certain variable like an object?

Tags: php, mysqli, ide

basically I get a mysqli object from a database class and store it in a variable like this:

```
$mysqli = Database::getInstance()->getMysqli();
```

after that declaration when I type `$mysqli->` I do not get any hints (autocomplete). I tried casting the object like this `(mysqli)$mysqli` but I get a syntax error. The object retrieved from getMysqli is in fact a mysqli object. I tested that with var_dump and the result is the following:

> object(mysqli)#2 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["client_info"]=> string(79) "mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 15d5c781cfcad91193dceae1d2cdd127674ddb3e $" ["client_version"]=> int(50011) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["host_info"]=> string(20) "127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(10) "5.7.11-log" ["server_version"]=> int(50711) ["stat"]=> string(138) "Uptime: 604869 Threads: 3 Questions: 1004 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 640 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 496 Queries per second avg: 0.001" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(92) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) }

If anybody could share his insight with me, I'd be forever grateful, thanks.

Comment: So you're wondering why your editor is not giving you the properties? Your editor usually only knows what Objects were created on that very page, when it comes to its autocomplete capabilities. So, if it was created on another page you won't get the call tips.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: @Machavity netbeans

Answer (score 0):

Took me a minute to figure out this was an IDE question

> after that declaration when I type $mysqli-> I do not get any hints (autocomplete)

The problem is that your IDE doesn't know what this line does

```
$mysqli = Database::getInstance()->getMysqli();
```

In most IDEs, you should be able to add a docblock and get it to autocomplete

```
/** @var \mysqli */
$mysqli = Database::getInstance()->getMysqli();
```

Alternatively, you could add a docblock above your `getMysqli()` function

```
/**
 * @return \mysqli
 */
```

Comment: thanks for responding, I tried that but no luck. I am using netbeans. could you tell me what IDE you know implements such feature?

Comment: in netbeans the syntax is a little different I guess. it goes like this: /* (at)var $mysqli mysqli */ ... I didn't find the right way to do the (at)return. however, the current solution is sufficient enough for me. thanks a ton. you are a life saver.

Comment: PHPStorm does a much better job than Netbeans for type hinting